# selected link not changing color

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation bar, and on selecting each link in the navigation bar only the content is changing in the body is changing. I did it using ajax for dynamic content changing, now I can bring change in the color of the menu items on hover, but on selecting the menu item is not changing the color.

**Also I could do like as long as I click on the menu I wanted to select the background image is changing then it is resetting to the old color.**

My code is as follows

HTML:

```
<div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#menuwrapper ul li a:active {
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 26px;
    color: red;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

then I have added a class to `li` and changed the css as follows

```
div#menuwrapper li.selected a {
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 26px;
    color: red;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

but nothing changes.

Here is my edited code can any one make some suggestions on this

```
  /* Define the body style */
 body {
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:12px;
}

/* We remove the margin, padding, and list style of UL and LI components */
#menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 }

/* We apply background color and border bottom white and width to 150px */
#menuwrapper ul li{
background-color:#333333;
border-bottom:solid 1px #222222;
width:56px;
height:56px;
margin-left:-240px;

cursor:pointer;
}

 /* We apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
 #menuwrapper ul li:hover{
 background-color:#4abbed;
 position:relative;
 }
 /* We apply the link style */
 #menuwrapper ul li a{
 padding:5px 15px;
 color:#ffffff;
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 }

div#menuwrapper ul li a:active {
margin-top: -17px;
margin-left: 0;
width: 26px;
color: red;
height: 56px;
background-color: #000;
}
div#menuwrapper li.selected a {
margin-top: -17px;
margin-left: 0;
width: 26px;
color: red;
height: 56px;
background-color: #000;
}


.nav a {
text-align:center;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
background: orange;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.menu:target
{
background: red;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="header">
<div id="menuwrapper">
<ul class="menu">
<li style="height:5px;background-color:#4abbed;border-bottom:solid 1px #4abbed;">
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="menu1" class="menu"><img src="images/home.png"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="menu2" class="menu"><img src="images/Description.png"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="menu3" class="menu" onClick="load('content', 'page2.php');">
<img src="images/Technical.png"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="menu4" class="menu" onClick="load('content', 'page3.php');">
<img src="images/Download.png"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a space here: `lia:active` -> `li a:active`

Comment: i have corrected it but on selecting the link the color is not changing

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: @sekar let me check i will reply back in few minutes

Comment: @sekar it is working ,but when i release the mouse click the black color is erasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:active` pseudo class will only take effect during the click, however if I understand correctly - what you want is the style to change after the click = 'selected'. (Is that correct?)

You can do this with pure css using The `:target` pseudo class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gaazS/)**

**Note:** You'll need a modern browser to use this method. (IE9+)

Also, take a look at **[this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)** which shows some clever ways to simulate click events with css (one of them being the :target pseudo class.

Comment: this one is working fine but how can i do it when i want to include div,li and ul

Comment: I have updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gaazS/1/ with ul and li

Comment: it is working in the jsfiddle but not for me ,any ways thanks a lot ,may be my jquery reference would be broken or something thanks

Comment: can you review my code i have added at the end of the question

Answer (score 1):

The `<li>` you want selected has to have a class "selected". Without `class="selected"` it will be treated like a normal " li " tag.
(notice also that `lia:active` should be `li a:active`)

For example:

```
<li class="selected"> 
<a href="#"><img src="images/home.png"></a>
</li>
```

Check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sUeVB/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
div#menuwrapper ul li a:active {
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 26px;
    color: red;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set background color for the 'selected' class, So add 'selected' class on click of each li like this.

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NhyVJ/)

Comment: @sekar can you please review my code i have added at the end of the question thanks